# abpio, project type module, when I start up the web.host project, error occurred

Tags: c#, abp

I just download the module template from abpio, the project type is module and has UI. I ran the project follow the [tutorial](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Startup-Templates/Module) , It is all ok when I start up the abpio.IdentityServer and abpio.HttpApi.Host project, the error occurred when I start up the abpio.Web.Host project.
error details:

> 2021-05-27 19:17:44.857 +08:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request GET "https://localhost:44329/api/abp/api-definition"
> 2021-05-27 19:17:44.857 +08:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request GET "https://localhost:44329/api/abp/api-definition"
> 2021-05-27 19:17:45.970 +08:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnel(Boolean async, HttpRequestHeaders headers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionFinder.GetApiDescriptionFromServerAsync(HttpClient client, String baseUrl)
> at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionCache.GetAsync(String baseUrl, Func`1 factory) at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionFinder.GetApiDescriptionAsync(HttpClient client, String baseUrl) at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionFinder.FindActionAsync(HttpClient client, String baseUrl, Type serviceType, MethodInfo method) at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor`1.MakeRequestAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
> at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor`1.MakeRequestAndGetResultAsync[T](IAbpMethodInvocation invocation) at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor`1.GetResultAsync(Task task, Type resultType)
> at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor`1.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation) at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed) at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo) at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync()
> at Volo.Abp.Validation.ValidationInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
> at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed)
> at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.b__14_0()
> at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.GetOrAddAsync(TCacheKey key, Func`1 factory, Func`1 optionsFactory, Nullable`1 hideErrors, Boolean considerUow, CancellationToken token)
> at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetAsync()
> at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemoteLanguageProvider.GetLanguagesAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.DefaultAbpRequestLocalizationOptionsProvider.GetLocalizationOptionsAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I don't know why, my Redis is online
[redis screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVNm9.png).
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> 2021-05-27 19:17:44.857 +08:00 [INF] Start processing HTTP request GET "https://localhost:44329/api/abp/api-definition" 2021-05-27 19:17:44.857 +08:00 [INF] Sending HTTP request GET "https://localhost:44329/api/abp/api-definition" 2021-05-27 19:17:45.970 +08:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely. at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)

Please check the logs of `https://localhost:44329` website.

Comment: Hi maliming, I have checked, there is no error log in the IdentityServer, the error logs are in Web.Host project. I open the link `https://localhost:44329/api/abp/api-definition` in chrome, it works fine. My colleague downloads the module template as well, and all the project works fine. that's super weird.